# vb.net comments file in the folder

Tags: vb.net

Why does the code return an empty result?

```vb
Private FileName As String

Private Sub btSave_Click(sender As Object, e As EventArgs) Handles btSave.Click
    Dim xlObj As Object
    xlObj = GetObject(, "Excel.Application")
    Dim myExcel As Microsoft.Office.Interop.Excel.Application = xlObj
    Dim BookPrint As Microsoft.Office.Interop.Excel.Workbook = myExcel.Workbooks(1)

    FileName = BookPrint.FullName
    BookPrint.BuiltinDocumentProperties("Subject").Value = "222"
    BookPrint.BuiltinDocumentProperties.Item("Comments").Value = "111"
    BookPrint.Save()
End Sub

Private Sub btRead_Click(sender As Object, e As EventArgs) Handles btRead.Click
    Dim Info As FileVersionInfo
    Info = FileVersionInfo.GetVersionInfo(FileName)

    MsgBox("Boock: " & FileName & vbCrLf & Info.ToString)
End Sub
```

Comment: `Sub` cannot return anything by definition

Comment: Can you explain what you mean by 'returns an empty result' in a bit more detail please?

Comment: I have given a comment to an excel file. It can be viewed by right-clicking and selecting details. And programmatically I do not see it(